# PHP CURL Request for 10K Times Same URL

Tags: php, curl

I have an Excel files approx. 1,29 MB and it has 11500 lines of data.

In my PHP code first i read whole files and put in arrays via PHPExcel/IOFactory library.

After the putting, in foreach loop i start to create $postvars for cUrl.

```
gonderi_referans=REF&alici=Sarah&alici_telefon=55544448885&alici_adres=Krg&alici_ulke=DE
```

In foreach loop the code will create 11500 times $postvars and make curl request.

```
    $url = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/api572.php";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);          
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postvars);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,30);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $response =json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
```

This operation takes approx 5 minutes. I want to do it in a faster way.
How can i do it?

Code read excel files in a 10 seconds, curl request it takes lots of times.

Comment: It's hard to guess without knowing your API, anyway, it looks like you should implement sone batch processing in it to send more then one input data at once.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use some batch-processing to minimize the number of sent requests, totally basic POC:

`excel-reader.php`:

```
    <?php

// Dummy data START
$dummyExcelRows = [];
for ($i = 0; $i <= 11500; $i++) {
    $dummyExcelRows[] = "gonderi_referans=REF&alici=Sarah&alici_telefon=55544448885&alici_adres=Krg&alici_ulke=DE&id=$i";
}
// Dummy data END

// Serialize multiple URI into one string START
$data = [];
foreach ($dummyExcelRows as $postvars) {
    $data[] = $postvars;
}
$dataToSend = ['payload' => json_encode($data)];
// Serialize multiple URI into one string END



$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/test/api572.php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataToSend);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
//    $response =json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

`api572.php`:

```
<?php

$decoded = json_decode($_POST['payload']);
foreach ($decoded as $row) {
    echo "Do something with $row <br/>";
    echo '<pre>';
    parse_str($row, $fakePost);
    print_r($fakePost);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```